# Do I have to 'pull' to merge the latest into my local branch in git?

Tags: git

Forgive my shallow understanding of `git`, but I see this pattern often and I'm wondering if it's necessary.  I see people doing this (working in `my-dev-branch` which was branched from `master`):

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout my-dev-branch
git merge master
```

Could you achieve the same thing with:

```
git fetch
git merge master
```

Or even:

```
git merge origin/master
```

Comment: I suggest doing ```git pull --rebase```

Comment: Read carefully what he is doing.  There are actually _two_ merges happening here (assuming his pull strategy does not use rebase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull` is by definition a combined `git fetch` followed by a `git merge` (barring exceptions when arguments or configuration override the default). [The documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) says so explicitly:

> Incorporates changes from a remote repository into the current branch. In its default mode, `git pull` is shorthand for `git fetch` followed by `git merge FETCH_HEAD`.

[Some](http://longair.net/blog/2009/04/16/git-fetch-and-merge/) [people](https://adamcod.es/2014/12/10/git-pull-correct-workflow.html) advise against using `git pull` at all. The reasons range from depriving you from a learning opportunity (that will lead to better understanding and usage of git) to the fact it automatically creates a relatively nasty merge commit. The bottom line being that it has the ability to do enough behind the scenes that it's hard to know exactly what the end result will be. Perhaps most importantly, it denies you the opportunity to examine the commits and choose how best to integrate them with your local changes.

`git merge origin/master` cannot, by itself, replace `git pull`. The reason for this is simple: it won't perform a fetch. `origin/master` is not actually referencing a branch in a remote repository. It's a local ref on locally stored commits with metadata indicating it should mirror a branch in a remote repository, so changes to the remote repository must be fetched before they're available in `origin/master`.

However, if the `master` branch is configured so that its tracking branch is `origin/master`, then `git merge` and `git merge origin/master` are equivalent:

> If no commit is given from the command line, merge the remote-tracking branches that the current branch is configured to use as its upstream.

([`git merge` Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))

So this would be equivalent if preceded by a fetch. It is less convenient and slightly more error prone, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are two concepts at work, and two types of merges which are happening.  The first type of merge is the one which occurs when you do the first two commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Assuming you have your pull strategy set to merge (rather than rebase), doing `git pull` on the `master` branch will first `fetch` any changes from the remote `master` and then *merge* them into your local copy of this branch.

The second merge which happens is when you do the following two commands:

```
git checkout my-dev-branch
git merge master
```

This switches to the `my-dev-branch` and then *merges* the local `master` branch into it.

Now here's where things get interesting.  Suppose you do this:

```
git checkout master
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

It turns out this is the same thing as doing what you had originally:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

Running `git fetch` will update your special *local* branches which track the remote.  In the case of `master` I expect this branch to be called `origin/master`.  So by merging this remote tracking branch into your local `master` you are effectively doing the same thing as merging the remote.